# What does the star mean in $\rightarrow ZZ^{(∗)}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, notation

What does the star mean in $\rightarrow ZZ^{(∗)}$? Z boson can neither be positive nor negative.

"For masses above 130 GeV, Higgs-boson decays, H $\rightarrow ZZ^{(∗)}$, where each Z decays to a pair of oppositely charged leptons, would provide the experimentally cleanest channel to study the properties of the Higgs boson."

Quoted from "The ATLAS Experiment at the CERN Large Hadron Collider"
http://nordberg.web.cern.ch/PAPERS/JINST08.pdf
page 2 or 3

Comment: Your link is behind a login/paywall - a DOI or pre-print link would be much more useful for people without access. Also, please state title and author of sources you rely on so that they can be reconstructed in case of link rot.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that this free publication would require a login.

Comment: I agree that the suggested question provides the answer to this one but to a noob like myself it isn't all that clear that $Z^*$ is a thing. I thought $ZZ^{(*)}$ was an unseparable entity so I think some people can still find it helpful.